# Did Obi-Wan Kenobi keep and wear Qui-Gon Jinn's poncho?

Tags: star-wars, obi-wan-kenobi

During his time on Tatooine with his padawan Obi-Wan Kenobi, Jedi Master Qui-Gon Jinn was seen wearing a poncho.

After the death of Qui-Gon, Obi-Wan kept his Master's lightsaber while building a new one, but at the same time, he was overcome with grief and experience some sadness and anxiety. Is it known if Obi-Wan Kenobi retained and ever wore the poncho of his old master?

[image]

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn%27s_cloak - there is a short clip in ANH where there is a cloak seen in Kenobi's hut that looks similar

Comment: @NKCampbell - There is also a brief scene in the official teaser of Obi-Wan Kenobi TV upcoming series that shows Kenobi wearing a poncho.

Comment: And did he also rifle his wallet for his giftcards and loose change?

Comment: ...'look at all these death sticks!'

Comment: Not his poncho, but Yoda (somehow) kept his cloak: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Qui-Gon_Jinn%27s_cloak

Comment: @BingoMehndra - The one seen in the [Kenobi trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TWTfhyvzTx0) looks very different. It's a different shape, it's made of a much rougher-looking material and a wider weave. Also it doesn't have the same patterning around the edges.

Comment: Waste perfectly good clothes, the Jedi do not.